# Android handler execution

Tags: android, handler, execution

First of all, see the code below.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    private final Handler mLeakyHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // AAAA
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Super. onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Post a message and delay its execution for 10 minutes.
        mLeakyHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // BBBB
            }
        }, 60 * 10 * 1000);

        // Go back to the previous Activity.
        finish();
    }
}
```

Ignore the fact that this can cause a memory leak (I know).
My questions are:

1. Will AAAA and BBBB be executed together? If not, which will be executed first?
2. According to the code, the message is not sent from onCreate() so does AAAA get an empty message?
3. When I run the code, AAAA doesn't seem to be executed. only BBBB is executed. Why is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Will AAAA and BBBB be executed together?

Only AAAA will be executed, When you `post()` a `Runnable`, you want the `Handler` to execute the code in the `Runnable`. For BBBB to be executed you must send a message to the `Handler` using one of the `sendMessage()` methods. See the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for details.

> According to the code, the message is not sent from onCreate() so does AAAA get an empty message?

No. As explained above, `handleMessage()` is not called.

> When I run the code, AAAA doesn't seem to be executed. only BBBB is executed. Why is it so?

Again, the first answer explains why